# libomniORB4.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: 14.04, bash, shared-library

I'm running a bash script and it gives the following error. Anyone has any idea how to sort this out?

> error while loading shared libraries: libomniORB4.so.1: wrong ELF
>   class: ELFCLASS64

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216000/gcc-error-wrong-elf-class-elfclass64

Comment: @bain, thanks but I'm not compiling anything.

Comment: Try to see `echo $LD_PRELOAD`, in case it points to the shared library try to unset the variable in the script. (Which script is it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker is complaining that it can't link a 64-bit library to a 32-bit program. If you  have a 32-bit system you should install 32-bit programs and libraries. If you have a 64-bit system, you can install either 32-bit or 64-bit programs, but if you install 32-bit you have to ensure that it will get linked against 32-bit libraries. If that is the case, see [this answer for how to do so.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436802/why-do-i-get-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgl-so-1-wrong-elf-class#436815)

Comment: Thanks. Would you tell me how I can install the 32 bit version of omniORB libs?

Comment: `apt-get install libomniorb4-1:i386`

Comment: Damn, thanks man. I've been banging my head for a while.