# Error loading shared library

Tags: 32-bit, libraries

I'm trying to run an old 32bit app on Ubuntu 14.04 x64. I've installed basic 32bit support via `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386`, but I now get a confusing message about shared libraries. It seems to be saying that it can't load my library because it's x64, but it's not - the whole thing is 32 bit.

```
user@ubuntu-develop:~/Desktop/MyApp/bin$ ./MyApp
./MyApp: error while loading shared libraries: libMyApp.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
user@ubuntu-develop:~/Desktop/MyApp/bin$ file libMyApp.so.1
libMyApp.so.1: symbolic link to `libMyApp.so.1.0.0' 
user@ubuntu-develop:~/Desktop/MyApp/bin$ file libMyApp.so.1.0.0
libMyApp.so.1.0.0: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=701d820fbe229a015ba4c56b61015c08bb2c4ac0, not stripped
user@ubuntu-develop:~/Desktop/MyApp/bin$ file MyApp
MyApp: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, BuildID[sha1]=1f736df460b9754633c7d67284674da395dc31c8, not stripped
```

I'm assuming it's actually still choking on some lower level dependency like `libc` or `libssl` or `libwhatsit`, but is there a way to find out which one the real culprit is, short of trial and error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get 'error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64' when I run Mercury?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436802/why-do-i-get-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgl-so-1-wrong-elf-class)

Comment: @gravity I looked at that, but in that case it's clearly actually trying to load an x64 system library from /lib. In my case it's trying to load an app-specific i386 library from the app's folder, but reporting an x64 error anyway.

Comment: That's kinda weird. Well, what I'd check in this situation: list symbols in the problem library, like `objdump -T libMyApp.so.1`, and pick a random one, then write a c *(not c++!)* file, like `void theRandomFunc(); int main () { theRandomFunc(); }` *(change «theRandomFunc»to whatever one you picked)*. Then try to build it like `gcc test.c -L/full/path/to/dir/withTheLib -lMyApp -o /dev/null -m32`. Do it just to see whether it would compile, or would linker complain about something. **UPD:** *added to compile command «-m32».*

Comment: The two binaries were compiled and/or linked with inconsistent relocation flags. See https://blogs.oracle.com/rie/entry/wrong_elf_class_requires_consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up starting over with a fresh CentOS i386 vm, and in the process of getting this running there found that the binary needs `libstdc++5`. Back on Ubuntu, installing that via `sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386` seems to have done the trick.